# Insert daily table to main table and update row in main table if key exists

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-insert

I am attempting to insert a daily table to a main table that has primary keys in it. I have the following architecture:

A python scripts that generates data in a pandas dataframe-> drops the daily table -> pushes to the daily table -> pushes the data from the daily table to the main table.

I cannot drop the main table but I can drop the daily table. At the moment I am using the following query to perform this:

```
 REPLACE INTO 
    mydb.{to_table}
 SELECT 
    *
 FROM 
     mydb.{from_table};
```

but I am getting the following error message:

```
ERROR (1062, "Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 'PRIMARY'") with sql 
                REPLACE INTO 
                    mydb.book_authors_v2
                SELECT 
                    *
                FROM 
                    mybd.books_authors_v2_daily;
```

I've tried using `INSERT ... UPDATE ON DUPLICATE KEY` but it did not manage to get it to work.

Is there any way of inserting the new rows from the daily table to the main table and updating the existing rows in the main table? There are nearly daily changes to the structure of the table, I would like to avoid having to manually define the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this looks like a good use case for the the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY` syntax.

Assuming that the primary key of your table is called `id`, and you have 3 other columns `col1`, `col2`, `col3` that you want to update on duplicate `id`, that would look like:

```
insert into mydb.book_authors_v2(id, col1, col2, col3)
select id, col1, col2, col3
from mybd.books_authors_v2_daily d
on duplicate key update set col1 = d.col1, col2 = d.col2, col3 = d.col3
```

Comment: There are over 100 columns and with near daily I was hoping for something were I wouldn't have to manually enter the column names

Comment: @Lukasz: as far as I know, there is no such shortcut. You have to enumerate the columns, at least in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause (you might get away with not listing the column names in the `insert` and using `select *` though - although this is not considered a good practice).